# Simplify BeginPackage with Package of Packages

Tags: packages

I have a group of Packages that I use to create a lot of other Packages. Let's see an example:

```
BeginPackage["testPack`",{"auxPack01`","auxPack02`","auxPack03`","auxPack04`"}]
testFunc::usage="testFunc[]"
Begin["`Private`"]
(*...package code...*)
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

My question is:

How can I create an `auxPack` (or some other simplification) so, I can just call it, instead of auxPack01, auxPack02 ... or a variable with all the definitions?

I tried to create a variable

```
$auxPacks={"auxPack01`","auxPack02`","auxPack03`","auxPack04`"}
```

So I could call

```
BeginPackage["testPack`", $auxPacks]
```

But didn't work. I also tried to create my own `BeginPackage` function as:

```
   myBeginPackage[packName_String]:=BeginPackage[packName,{"auxPack01`","auxPack02`","auxPack03`","auxPack04`"}]
```

But didn't work either.

Something similar this last try would be the best option to me.  Any clue?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "didn't work" part, because your both solutions work for me. Problem with them is that `$auxPacks` or `myBeginPackage` needs to live in some context, which needs to be on `$ContextPath` when loading package.

Comment: You could create a "grouping package": ``BeginPackage["auxPack`",{"auxPack01`", ...}]; EndPackage[]`` and then call ``BeginPackage["testPack`", "auxPack`"]``

Comment: Have you used any of suggestions, if so, maybe post selfanswer? :)

Comment: @Kuba I will post

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115502/second-argument-of-beginpackage-with-nested-package-loading